# Exception while trying to compile JODA time 2.1 source

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to support [SystemV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_V) time zones in Joda time.So as mentioned in this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10697902/306855),i tried recompiling after commenting the lines in SystemV data file.But while compiling it gives this exception :

```
 [java] Exception in thread "main" org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Value 292278995 for year must be in the range [-292275054,292278993]
     [java]     at org.joda.time.field.FieldUtils.verifyValueBounds(FieldUtils.java:217)
     [java]     at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicYearDateTimeField.set(BasicYearDateTimeField.java:82)
     [java]     at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicYearDateTimeField.add(BasicYearDateTimeField.java:63)
     [java]     at org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$OfYear.next(DateTimeZoneBuilder.java:575)
     [java]     at org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$Recurrence.next(DateTimeZoneBuilder.java:761)
     [java]     at org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$Rule.next(DateTimeZoneBuilder.java:863)
     [java]     at org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$RuleSet.nextTransition(DateTimeZoneBuilder.java:1091)
     [java]     at org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$RuleSet.firstTransition(DateTimeZoneBuilder.java:1029)
     [java]     at org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder.toDateTimeZone(DateTimeZoneBuilder.java:351)
     [java]     at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoCompiler.compile(ZoneInfoCompiler.java:391)
     [java]     at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoCompiler.main(ZoneInfoCompiler.java:136)
```

Any idea what this is ?

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey :1.6 .Will JDK version affect this ?

Comment: Its the only thing I could image making a difference. Can you give the exact update and whether it is OpenJDK or HotSpot or something else?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.6) (6b22-1.10.6-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode).This is what i get when i type "java -version".I'm using ubuntu 11.04. But i'm compiling using ant script in eclipse.In eclipse i'm using           java version "1.6.0_16"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: That's not such an old version that it should matter but I would try Oracle/Hotspot Java 6 update 35.

Answer (score 0):

Look to the `joda-time-2.1.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` we can see that requared JDK is
`Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_22`.
So use it, instead if you.

You have bad zoneinfo files. I build joda lib without any problems, using JDK 1.6_22.

At building process we have next

```
main:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\js\target\classes\org\joda\time\tz\data
     [java] Writing zoneinfo files
     [java] Writing ZoneInfoMap
Executed tasks
```

here your building fails

Comment: You have bad zoneinfo files. I build joda api without any problems.

Comment: Can you paste this file in pastebin?

Comment: Tried with JDK 1.6_22 ,still the same exception.Then while commenting the zones did u leave a space,if so it will not throw any exception ,it will just silently ignore the SystemV times zones.

Comment: I'm able to compile after commenting the first 2 lines in rules.